# How to calculate number of days in redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I would like to calculate number of days between two dates in redshift but the function should take into account the time that's mean day=0 if there is less than 24 hours between the dates like Timestampdiff function in MySQL. Datediff is not relevant here .

Comment: What is the TYPE of the fields you wish to subtract? Are they stored as TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a `DATEDIFF(hours, start, end) / 24` to count the number of hours, then divide by 24 to get the number of whole days, eg:

```
db=# create table t (a TIMESTAMP, b TIMESTAMP);
CREATE TABLE
db=# insert into t values ('2015-08-19 03:56:39'::timestamp, '2015-08-23 02:22:18'::timestamp);
INSERT 0 1
db=# insert into t values ('2015-08-19 03:56:39'::timestamp, '2015-08-23 10:22:18'::timestamp);
INSERT 0 1
db=# select a, b, datediff(hours, a, b) / 24 as whole_days from t;
          a          |          b          | whole_days 
---------------------+---------------------+------------
 2015-08-19 03:56:39 | 2015-08-23 02:22:18 |          3
 2015-08-19 03:56:39 | 2015-08-23 10:22:18 |          4
(2 rows)
```

See also:

- [Amazon Redshift Data Types documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_Supported_data_types.html)
- [Working with Dates and Times in PostgreSQL](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Working_with_Dates_and_Times_in_PostgreSQL)